# clojure.core/refer failing with "$ does not exist"

Tags: clojure

when loading this project:

```
(defproject incanter "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [incanter "1.3.0"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[swank-clojure/swank-clojure "1.4.0"]])
```

and using it like this:

```
 (use '(incanter stats))
```

I get this cryptic error message:

```
$ does not exist
  [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalAccessError]

... lots-o-stack ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed that the name of your project is the same as one of the dependencies. Assuming you are using the Leiningen defaults, given by the `FIXME` in your project map,  you most likely have the file `src/incanter/core.clj` in your project.

Given all that, I was able to reproduce the error by creating a new project with the name "incanter" and invoking the same command you did inside a REPL. I then renamed the projects "incanter" namespace to something else (also changing it in core.clj) and invoked the `use` command in the REPL again. This time I didn't receive the error.

Side note: I was able to reproduce this issue with out any `:dev-dependencies`.